# How to be change the volume of a sound effect within pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am wondering how to reduce the sound effect of an individual sound. 
I know that it is possible with music but i cant work out how to do it per sound.
Some of my sounds are too loud compared to the rest.

```
##load game sounds
shoot_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(snd_folder, "shoot.wav"))
invader_killed = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(snd_folder, "death.wav"))
player_killed = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(snd_folder, "willdeath.wav")) 
##load game music
pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join(snd_folder, 'MusicSample.ogg'))
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.01)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, sound shares the same function as music according to the pygame documentation. So just do:

```
shoot_sound.set_volume(0.01)
invader_killed.set_volume(0.01)
player_killed.set_volume(0.01)
```